# Isset doesn't work after include

Tags: php

I'm having a very very weird issue that I'm unable to see...

I tend to have a "check" in scripts that return things through AJAX so, if you don't give it some key value to POST or GET, it won't work.

So, in my script I have this:

```
if (isset($_GET['end'])){

do something;
}
else
die ('You are doing it wrong');
```

So, having this URL:

```
calendarEvents.php?start=1314568800&end=1317592800&_=1316538623362
```

SHOULD pass the isset. In fact, if I echo the isset result or even the `$_GET['end']` itself, it ouputs right. Seriously, what's wrong?

Edit: var_dump results

```
array
  'start' => string '1314568800' (length=10)
  'end' => string '1317592800' (length=10)
  '_' => string '1316538623362' (length=13)
```

Edit once again:

I'm including a file here which has another include inside. If I include both files inside the failing file, it works, but if include ones that includes another one it fails. No inception allowed inside PHP...

BTW... Thanks for downvoting. I would like that someone explain me why a valid question with a real problem is downvoted, because don't know how to solve it?

Comment: What behavior are you looking for?

Comment: I've tried this and it is working fine. What is happening on your end, is the `die` clause executed ?

Comment: I just want to avoid that you call it in a wrong way or from a wrong script. If someone try to enter this script manually, you won't see any exceptions because it simply won't try to do nothing.

Comment: @danishgoel yep. The die is executed. I have this working on many many scripts of my page so, I don't understand what's wrong

Comment: Are you saying that `echo $_GET['end'];` shows the number but `if (isset($_GET['end']))` doesn't work? I find that hard to believe :D

What about `var_dump($_GET)`?

Comment: are you sure you're not sending it via POST? If you change $_GET to $_REQUEST does it fix your problem?

Comment: if ($_GET['end']) is a little bit dirty because if it's not set, it will throw a Warning which I don't like. var_dump before the IF shows this: array
  'start' => string '1314568800' (length=10)
  'end' => string '1317592800' (length=10)
  '_' => string '1316538623362' (length=13)

Comment: @stanislav: `if ($_GET['end'])` fails if end is 0 or empty. However, isset would always return true if `end` is present as a query varname.

Comment: Impossible to answer. Present a testcase if you've found an actual problem.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal I'm posting a real testcase. With a real URL so you can see it's a GET

Comment: I don't get the point of the one who downrated the question since it's well doccumented and, seriously, I've tried to solve it by myself

Comment: @Marshall $_REQUEST doesn't solve the issue neither. I'm accessing it by the URL not by AJAX. I noticed that suddenly, the Ajax part wasn't working so I went to look what was happening.

Comment: I managed to solve it, by myself. Thanks for your help...

Comment: @Antonio Laguna: What was the solution?

Comment: @webbiedave it's on the question itself...

Comment: @AntonioLaguna Well, that was weird. I'm glad you've worked it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm including a file here which has another include inside. If I include both files inside the failing file, it works, but if include ones that includes another one it fails. No inception allowed inside PHP...

Answer (score 0):

If your url is being submitted from a webpage it might be interpreting `&end` as an entity and submitting an invalid url to the server.

Comment: It's not that, in fact doing echo isset($_GET['end']) outputs 1